# Java tile map using Libgdx: finding tile at mouse position

Tags: java, libgdx

I've looked at several examples of people creating tile maps, and I am unable to get the tile position where my mouse is pointed at.

I am using a spritebatch and GameTile[][] to create the map. Keep in mind that the tiles themselves are isometric and not actually a square.

The method renderMap() is where the map is actually is being rendered. createMap() just sets the initial GameTiles for an empty map.

The map is able to be dragged and zoomed in and out using Ortho camera.

Zooming out gives me an issue as well, the tiles seem to be shifted over on click

```
public class MapEditor implements GameScene {
    private GameContext context;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    public static GameTile[][] tiles; //GameTile.WIDTH = 64 & GameTile.HEIGHT =48

    public static final int MAP_WIDTH = 20;
    public static final int MAP_HEIGHT = 36;

    public MapEditor(GameContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        tiles = new GameTile[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];
    }
    @Override
    public void create() {
        renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        this.batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    }
    public void createMap() {
        // Create the sea tiles
        for (int x = 0; x < MAP_WIDTH; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < MAP_HEIGHT; y++) {
                if (y < 3 || y > 32) {
                    if(tiles[x][y] == null) {
                        tiles[x][y] = safezone;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(tiles[x][y] == null) {
                        tiles[x][y] = cell;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }

   @Override
    public void update(){
        // update the camera
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0,0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        renderMap();
        batch.end();
    }
    public int getTileX(float x, float y) {
        /*
         * getRegionWidth() = TILE_WIDTH_HALF 
         * getRegionHeight() = TILE_HEIGHT_HALF
         * these are the ones being added to worldCoords.x/y
        */
        Vector3 worldCoords = camera.unproject(new Vector3(x, y, 0));
        return (int)((TILE_WIDTH_HALF * ((-TILE_HEIGHT_HALF + (worldCoords.y + TILE_HEIGHT_HALF)) / 
                TILE_HEIGHT_HALF) + (worldCoords.x + TILE_WIDTH_HALF)) / TILE_WIDTH_HALF) / 2;
    }
    
    public int getTileY(float x, float y) {
        /*
         * getRegionWidth() = TILE_WIDTH_HALF 
         * getRegionHeight() = TILE_HEIGHT_HALF
         * these are the ones being added to worldCoords.x/y
        */
        Vector3 worldCoords = camera.unproject(new Vector3(x, y, 0));
        return (int)(((-TILE_HEIGHT_HALF * (TILE_WIDTH_HALF + (worldCoords.x + TILE_WIDTH_HALF)) / 
                TILE_WIDTH_HALF) + (worldCoords.y + TILE_HEIGHT_HALF)) / TILE_HEIGHT_HALF) / 2;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean handleClick(float x, float y, int button) {
        int tileX = getTileX(x,y);
        int tileY = getTileY(x,y);

        System.out.println("Tile:"+tileX + ","+tileY);
    }

    private void renderMap() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < tiles[i].length; j++) {
                TextureRegion region = tiles[i][j].getRegion();
                int x = (i * GameTile.TILE_WIDTH / 2) - (j * GameTile.TILE_WIDTH / 2) - region.getRegionWidth() / 2;
                int y = (i * GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT / 2) + (j * GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT / 2) - region.getRegionHeight() / 2;
                if (canDraw(x, y, GameTile.TILE_WIDTH, GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT)) {
                    batch.draw(region, x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Actual tile before doing anything to it;

[image]

Actual:

[image]
Desired:

[image]

Comment: Please note that this site is not a debugging service. Copy-pasting large slabs of code into the question and asking us to debug it is off-topic. However, we can help you with *specific* questions about small *parts* of your code (a few lines), ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to narrow its focus and remove all code not directly relevant. Eg perhaps leave just the method with the problem.

Comment: Hello maybe you have already think about this but why don't you use actor for your game tile ?  Each tile Is an actor an you can just add listener on the tile. This will allow you to avoid this mapping between  mouse position and tile posiiton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting Cartesian coordinates to isometric is (sort of) done like this:

```
float isometricX = cartesianX - cartesianY;
float isometricY = (cartesianX + cartesianY) * 0.5f;
```

The formula needs to be scaled by the *height-to-width* ratio of the tiles as well and I think that is where it's going wrong in your code.

Given an unprojected `worldMousePosition` you can get the coordinates and tile coordinates like this:

```
    float r = (float) TILE_HEIGHT / (float) TILE_WIDTH;

    float mapx = (worldMousePosition.x / TILE_HEIGHT + worldMousePosition.y / (TILE_HEIGHT * r)) * r;
    float mapy = (worldMousePosition.y / (TILE_HEIGHT * r) - (worldMousePosition.x / TILE_HEIGHT)) * r;
    worldPosition = new Vector2(mapx - 0.5f, mapy + 0.5f); // -.5/+.5 because the drawing isn't aligned to the tile, it's aligned to the image

    int tileX = (int) worldPosition.x;
    int tileY = (int) worldPosition.y;
```

[image]

Full source code for the example above:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class SandboxGame extends Game {
    public static final int TILE_NONE = -1;
    public static final int MAP_WIDTH = 20;
    public static final int MAP_HEIGHT = 36;
    public static final int TILE_WIDTH = 64;
    public static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 48;

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private BitmapFont font;
    private Vector3 unprojectVector = new Vector3();
    private Vector2 worldMousePosition = new Vector2();
    private Vector2 worldPosition = new Vector2();
    private Texture[] textures;

    private int[][] tiles = new int[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        font =  new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("default.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("default.png"), false);
        textures = new Texture[] {
            new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("tile.png"))
        };

        for(int x = 0; x < MAP_WIDTH; ++x) {
            for(int y = 0; y < MAP_HEIGHT; ++y) {
                int rnd = MathUtils.random(10);
                if (rnd < 1)
                    tiles[x][y] = TILE_NONE;
                else
                    tiles[x][y] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        float scrollSpeed = 64;
        float zoomSpeed = 2;

        float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A))
            camera.position.x -= delta * scrollSpeed;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D))
            camera.position.x += delta * scrollSpeed;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W))
            camera.position.y += delta * scrollSpeed;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))
            camera.position.y -= delta * scrollSpeed;

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.Q))
            camera.zoom = Math.min(camera.zoom + zoomSpeed * delta, 8.0f);
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.E))
            camera.zoom = Math.max(camera.zoom - zoomSpeed * delta, 0.5f);

        camera.update();

        int mx = Gdx.input.getX();
        int my = Gdx.input.getY();

        camera.unproject(unprojectVector.set(mx, my, 0.0f));
        worldMousePosition.set(unprojectVector.x, unprojectVector.y);
        float r = (float) TILE_HEIGHT / (float) TILE_WIDTH;

        float mapx = (worldMousePosition.x / TILE_HEIGHT + worldMousePosition.y / (TILE_HEIGHT * r)) * r;
        float mapy = (worldMousePosition.y / (TILE_HEIGHT * r) - (worldMousePosition.x / TILE_HEIGHT)) * r;
        worldPosition = new Vector2(mapx - 0.5f, mapy + 0.5f); // -.5/+.5 because the drawing isn't aligned to the tile, it's aligned to the image

        int tileX = (int) worldPosition.x;
        int tileY = (int) worldPosition.y;

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();

        for (int col = MAP_WIDTH - 1; col >= 0; --col) {
            for (int row = MAP_HEIGHT - 1; row >= 0; --row) {
                if (tiles[col][row] != TILE_NONE) {
                    Texture texture = textures[tiles[col][row]];
                    int x = (col * TILE_WIDTH / 2) - (row * TILE_WIDTH / 2);
                    int y = (col * TILE_HEIGHT / 2) + (row * TILE_HEIGHT / 2);
                    batch.setColor(col == tileX && row == tileY ? Color.GRAY : Color.WHITE);
                    batch.draw(texture, x, y);

                }
            }
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)) {
            for (int col = MAP_WIDTH - 1; col >= 0; --col) {
                for (int row = MAP_HEIGHT - 1; row >= 0; --row) {
                    int x = (col * TILE_WIDTH / 2) - (row * TILE_WIDTH / 2);
                    int y = (col * TILE_HEIGHT / 2) + (row * TILE_HEIGHT / 2);
                    font.draw(batch, String.format("(%d, %d)", col, row), x, y);
                }
            }
        }

        String str = String.format("World position (%.2f, %.2f), Tile (%d, %d)", worldPosition.x, worldPosition.y, (int)worldPosition.x, (int)worldPosition.y);
        font.draw(batch, str, worldMousePosition.x, worldMousePosition.y);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant respond to bornander's post, but my tweak would be at

```
    int tileX = (int) Math.Floor(worldPosition.x);
    int tileY = (int) Math.Floor(worldPosition.y);
```

Where simple (int) cast will provide wrong position around 0 with negative values, if there are tiles, while using Math.Floor will work as intended.